# Tooltip for Collapsible Animated Indented Tree

Tags: tooltip

I have been working with the Collapsible Animated Indented Tree: http://bl.ocks.org/tchaymore/1249394 by tchaymore’s Block 1249394.

However, I am fairly new to D3 and cannot make the tooltip to work. I need each of the nodes to say something different. The necessary files can be found here: https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1093025 as it draws the data from an external file source (the JSON file).

Comment: You should show us what you have tried to do to set the tooltip

Comment: Where should I attach my files? Sorry, I'm a newbie here.

Comment: You should insert relevant code on the answer. You are not allowed to upload scripts

Comment: Okay I went to the code section to edit the question but I'm confused as to where I should insert the details. I have a HTML file, a JSON file and a CSS file (like the original). All I did was change the name of the different nodes. If I could see how you do it in the original link, I could make it work in mine as well. Any idea on how to do that?